# Conformal map from exterior of disk to strip in upper half plane

Tags: complex-analysis, linear-transformations, conformal-geometry

I've been looking into conformal maps recently to try and solve a problem I'm looking at. I'd like to flatten a coordinate system from polar onto cartesian, and transform all of the geometry from one coordinate system to the other.

Specifically, I'd like to take a point at $z=i$ on the unit disk, and map that point onto the origin $z' = 0$ of a cartesian coordinate system. I'd also like to take points $z = -i \pm \epsilon$ where epsilon is a positive infinitesimal and map that to a point $z' = \pm \pi$. Any point $z > |1|$, I'd like to map to a cartesian point like $z = (r,\theta)$ where $r > 1$ maps to $z' = (x,iy)$ as $r = i(y+1)$ and $x = \theta$.

I've figured out how to map the disk onto the upper half plane, but this stretches the lengths $-2i \pm \epsilon$ out to $\pm \infty$, and I'd prefer to have the map confined to just a strip.

Is there a map that does this? Computationally, it's easy enough to set y = r-1, and x = theta, but I'm hoping to map functions and data as well. This is kind of a new field of math for me, so please forgive me if I'm asking rather naïve questions.

Comment: I do not understand "$z' = (x,iy)$ as $r = i(y+1)$ and $x = \theta$" + to which "strip in the upper half plane" do you want to map the exterior of the unit disc? Anyway, they are not even homeomorphic, since the first one is [simply connected](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simply_connected_space) and the second one is not.

Comment: I've been playing with it for a while today. Here's the sequence that I think I'm trying to make: First, I want to move from a disk centered at (0, -r) to be centered at the origin, so I think this is z' = z + r. Next I want to rotate the coordinates so theta = 0 is now along the positive imaginary axis, so z'' = i*z'. Then I want to map from polar onto cartesian, and I think that is best done with z''' = log(z''). Since log maps to the right half plane, and I want it to be the upper half plane, I rotate that to be z'''' = i*z'''. Altogether I think this is w = i*Log(i*(z+r)). Is that right?

Comment: The *principle branch* of the log function maps all of $\Bbb C\setminus \{0\}$ to $\Bbb R + i(-\pi,\pi]$. You are free to choose any branch you want, not just the principle one, but that just moves the vertical strip that is its image right or left. In no case is it an entire half plane. You can even make more exotic cuts to define a branch of the logarithm, in which case you get something more like a wavy strip. But it will still be just a strip, not a half-plane.

Comment: @AnneBauval, I think I found a mapping that works. But to answer your questions, the strip in the upper half plane I wanted to transform into was $-\pi \leq x \leq pi$ and $iy \geq 0$. The interior of the disk I wanted to map to $iy < 0$.